# Angular duplicate items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a problem.

I have a JSON comming from backend to my frontend. It looks like:

```
{
    "title": "Interrupted",
    "image": "1",
    "timestamp": "1403617939848",
    "image" : "1",
    "categories": ["News","News","Handball","Handball"]
},
```

My view looks like:

```
   <!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="" ng-app="videoApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Latest videos</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="public">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/libraries/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="VideoListCtrl">
        <header class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-white">
            LATEST VIDEOS
            <span><select class="favorite-selector">
                <option value="{{category}}" ng-repeat="category in categories">{{category}}</option>
            </select> <button class="btn-danger">Add to favorite</button></span>
            <span class="results"></span>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="category-list">
                <li><a href="#" class="categories-filter" data-value="all">All videos</a></li>
                <li ng-repeat="category in categories"><a href="#" ng-click="getFilteredResults(category, videos)" class="categories-filter" data-value="{{category}}">&nbsp;{{category}}</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="video-container" id="video-container">
                <article class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 video' dir-paginate="video in videos | itemsPerPage: 12">
                    <div class='video-image'><img class='img-responsive img' src='img/{{video.image ? video.image : "1" }}.jpeg'>
                        <img class='player img-responsive' src='img/icon.png' width='75px' height='75px'>
                    </div>
                    <p class='video-title'><strong>{{video.title}}</strong></p>
                    <p class='video-timestamp'>{{video.timestamp}}</p>
                    <span class='categories'>
                        <li ng-repeat="categ in video.categories | unique">{{categ}}&nbsp;</li>
                    </span>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
                    <dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script src="js/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular/ui-utils.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libraries/underscore.js"></script>


    <script src="js/controllers/VideoListCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters/CategoryFilter.js"></script>
        <script src="js/filters/ArticleFilter.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/dirPagination.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
var videoApp = angular.module('videoApp', ['videoAppFilters', 'ui.unique', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

videoApp.controller('VideoListCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
    $http.get('http://academy.tutoky.com/api/json.php').success(function (data) {
        $scope.videos = data;
        $scope.categories = $filter('categoryFilter')(data);
    });

    $scope.getFilteredResults = function (category, data) {
        $scope.videos = $filter('articleFilter')(category, data);
        return $scope.videos;
    };
});
```

Article filter:

```
angular.module('videoAppFilters').filter('articleFilter', function () {
    return function (category, data) {
        var filteredData = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < data[i].categories.length; j++) {
                    if (data[i].categories[j] == category) {
                        filteredData.push(data[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        return filteredData;
    };
});
```

Categories are filtered with unique filter and after loading page everything works. But, I' want to filter articles by category after clicking on category name.

So when i click on Handball for example, it should show me only results that have Handball category.

But, when i click on category name, angular throw exception about duplicates. I don't really understand why its able to handle them with unique on first load but after model changes, it's not.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you post the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this. There were 2 problems, one was that I needed to get rid of duplicates again after rewriting that $scope.videos, because the second time unique filter in categories in did not proceed ( dunno why ).

I did it like this:

```
$scope.getFilteredResults = function (category, data) {
    $scope.videos = $filter('articleFilter')(category, data);
    return $scope.videos;
};
```

and add unique to videos ng-repeat like

```
<article class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 video' dir-paginate="video in videos | unique | itemsPerPage: 12">
```

Another problem was that I was rewriting $scope.videos so after every filtration there were less and less results, cause it was filtered over and over again. I had to create another variable that was working as source of data but were not rewritten.

So instead of

```
$scope.videos = data;
```

I have

```
$scope.videos = data;
$scope.allData = data;
```

Also I had to change the onClick action to pass allData instead of videos

```
 <li ng-repeat="category in categories"><a href="#" ng-click="getFilteredResults(category, allData)" class="categories-filter">&nbsp;{{category}}</a></li>
```

Comment: wow!, you post the question along with answer with no time gap in between!

Comment: I somehow found a solution faster than i thought :D